# Remove <br /> tags from PHP csv export

Tags: php

I am using the following code to export data into a CSV file using PHP. The problem is that one of the fields has line breaks in it the CSV file shows multiple `<br />` tags. Is there an easy way to remove these from the output file?

```
<?php


$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = $conn->query($query);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=output.csv');

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
    echocsv(array_keys($row));
}

while ($row) {
    echocsv($row);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}

function echocsv($fields)
{
    $separator = '';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
            $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
        }
        echo $separator . $field;
        $separator = ',';
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

Thanks,

John

Comment: You want to only remove the tag '<br />' or also the 'new line'?

Comment: Just remove the '<br />' tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried str_replace? -> http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php

```
$html = 'Lorep Ipsum<br/>Dolor Sit Amet';
echo '<p>' . $html . '</p>';

$html= str_replace('<br/>', "", $html);
echo '<p>' . $html . '</p>';
```

Output:

```
Lorep Ipsum
Dolor Sit Amet

Lorep IpsumDolor Sit Amet
```